# unable to install gem capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

When we install the gem :$ gem install capybara-webkit, we got following error, Please help;

```
  $ gem install capybara-webkit
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/zapbuild/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Command 'qmake -spec linux-g++ ' not available

Makefile not found

Gem files will remain installed in /home/zapbuild/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.1.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/zapbuild/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.1.0/capybara-webkit-1.1.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Did you follow https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit ? (capybara-webkit requires QT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this

first of all run this command

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqt4-core libqt4-gui
```

after that run this command

```
gem install capybara-webkit -v '0.11.0'
```